# Configuration Profile iOS - length of the name and identifier field

Tags: ios, configuration-profile

While creating configuration profile say using  iphone Configuration Utility, there is no limit in the character length for Name and Identifier fields.
But i have a requirement where i have to collect details about the configuration profile and store it into my DB. And in the DB i have to set the length to these fields.

Theorotically can someone suggest a meaningful length for these fields.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually ios using coredata DB, where fields are not required length so if you using coredta then no need to worry about length of name.
But if you are using other DB then it is depend on you how much length of name you want to store.